# Integrating non-elementary functions

Tags: integration, special-functions, elementary-functions

An elementary function is a function that can be represented by a finite number of exponentials, logarithms, nth roots, and constants through composition. Clearly, an non-elementary function that is not elementary.

There are plenty of elementary functions such that integrating said function results in a non-elementary functions. Some quick ones that come to mind are $e^{x^2}$, $x^x$, and $\frac{1}{\ln{x}}$.

My question:

> Is it possible to find a non-elementary function $f(x)$ such that $\int f(x)dx$ is an elementary function?

My intuition tells me *no*, but he's been wrong plenty of times before.

Comment: Think it for a little while. What operation undoes the integration? How does it act on elementary functions?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Differentiating any function finds the infinitesimal change in f(x) with respect to x. On an elementary function, this is no different.

Comment: $(\int f(x)dx)'=f(x)$. How ugly does it look the derivative of an elementary function?

Comment: Got it. The derivative of an elementary function _is always_ an elementary function. Thus, if $\int f(x) dx$ is elementary, $f(x)$ must be elementary.

Comment: @Bonnaduck it is encouraged to answer your question by yourself once you got it and accept your answer. Once you do it, your question will disappear from the list of unanswered questions, which is designed to contain questions that should be answered, which is not the case of your question anymore.

Comment: It is possible to express an elementary function $f$ with the help of non-elementary functions. But nevertheless, $f$ remains an elementary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of an elementary function is always an elementary function. Thus, if $\int f(x)dx$  is elementary, $f(x)$  must be elementary.